# MySQL where clause not returning expected value

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   hayabusa.customer_staging 
WHERE  tin = "888-596-592" 
        OR gsis_sss_no = "bp0279638" 
        OR last_name LIKE "%dela cruz%" 
        OR first_name LIKE "%jose%" 
        OR date_of_birth = "8/8/1978" 
        OR gender = "male" 
           AND parent_id = 0 
           AND is_proccessed = 0 
           AND id > 27 
           AND ( filename = "sample cif csv file - copy.csv" 
                  OR filename = "sample cif csv file2.csv" ) 
GROUP  BY tin, 
          gsis_sss_no, 
          last_name, 
          first_name, 
          date_of_birth, 
          gender 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN tin = "888-596-592" THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
          end, 
          id 
LIMIT  1;
```

But it's returning a row with an `id` of 3 and a `filename` which is not in the `where` clause. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Always use parantheses when you use OR and AND. Try adding those and everything should be fine

Comment: Can you share the full record you don't think it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` in MySQL (and most databases), so your current query is treating your `AND` condition with the filename as being optional.  Try rewriting the `WHERE` clause as this:

```
WHERE
    (tin = "888-596-592" 
    OR gsis_sss_no = "bp0279638" 
    OR last_name LIKE "%dela cruz%" 
    OR first_name LIKE "%jose%" 
    OR date_of_birth = "8/8/1978" 
    OR gender = "male")
       AND parent_id = 0 
       AND is_proccessed = 0 
       AND id > 27 
       AND ( filename = "sample cif csv file - copy.csv" 
              OR filename = "sample cif csv file2.csv" )
```

Also, I don't know which columns you intend to select, but using `SELECT *` here is probably inappropriate.  Instead, you should list out which columns you want to select.  Strictly speaking, only columns appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause or columns which are inside aggregate functions are eligible for selection in your query.